# Rogers (Kleene)'s fixed-point theorem and the Y combinator

Tags: computability

In the [Wikipedia article on Rogers' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_recursion_theorem), it is stated that the proof given by Rogers is a construction of a partial recursive function which implements the Y combinator.

I've just a basic knowledge of both the theory of recursive functions and the lambda calculus, however I (think I) know what the Y combinator is and what can be achieved, in terms of fixed points of functions, by using it.
Having said that, I am unable to see the Y combinator in that proof.